# Scrollbar doesn't work in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a problem, when I put a Scrollbar it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<ScrollView >
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="244dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="332dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

This is the listview

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the end

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="42dp" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="281dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Listview inside a ScrollView is not a working solution. You should use header  and footer of the ListView instead.

Main content: the list

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/your_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Header view in separate xml layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Footer view in separate xml layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="281dp" />
```

Code: You must add header and footer before you set the adapter

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_list);
View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.header_view, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, listView, false);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then you will have a fully scrollable ListView with a TextView above and an EditText below it.